# Multiple CSS backgrounds with middle repeating portion

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to use multiple background images on a single div with a top portion, a middle repeating portion, and a bottom portion. The issue is that the repating portion repeats throughout the whole div.

**Does anyone know of a technique to restrict a repeating background image to a particular portion of a div? If that is not feasible, do you know if it's possible to push the `background_middle_repeating.png` background images behind the top and bottom background images?**

CSS

```
div {
  background:
    url(../images/background_top.png) no-repeat 50% 0%,
    url(../images/background_middle_repeating.png) repeat-y 50% 100px,
    url(../images/background_bottom.png) no-repeat 50% 100%;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Background layers are created in the order they are specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering), top-down; with this in mind, to push the middle layer behind the top and bottom layers, declare it last:

```
div {
  background:
    url(../images/background_top.png) no-repeat 50% 0%,
    url(../images/background_bottom.png) no-repeat 50% 100%,
    url(../images/background_middle_repeating.png) repeat-y 50% 100px;
}
```

Note however that if portions of your top and bottom images are transparent, this will cause the middle image to show through those transparent portions. In such a case you will need to find a different way to restrict the area of the middle background image through some other means. Depending on your layout, this could be as simple as filling in those transparent areas using an image editor, or this could require the use of pseudo-elements or assigning the top and bottom images to different elements altogether.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. You anticipated the issue that I'm now having with the middle image showing through the transparent portions of the top and bottom images. I'm still trying to solve my problem, preferably without modifying the markup. I am going to try using the `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements to solve this problem.